# Error al enviar imagen de un formulario con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de enviar un formulario mediante post con un campo tipo **file** para subir una foto .

El problema es que no puedo enviar la imagen cargada y aparece el siguiente error :

**"TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement" .**

Alguien sabe a que se debe y como solucionarlo?.Soy bastante nuevo en esto asi que estoy experimentando pero no encuentro la razón de este error

El formulario está echo con html y php .L carga del formulario queincluye el campo file está hecho con Ajax y Jquery:

```html
<form  action="" method="post" id="form_agregar_producto" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <h5 class="text-center text-info">Formulario</h5>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="producto" class="text-white">Producto</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producto" name="producto" placeholder="Nombre del producto" value="" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="precio" class="text-white">Precio</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="precio" placeholder="Precio del producto" name="precio">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cantidad" class="text-white">Cantidad</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" placeholder="Cantidad del producto">
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
        <label for="imagen" class="text-white">Imagen</label>
        <div class="prevPhoto">
            <span class="delPhoto notBlock">X</span>
            <label for="imagen"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="upimg">
            <input type="file" name="imagen" id="imagen">
        </div>
        <div id="form_alert"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mt-2 mb-3" id="submit_agregar_producto" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Enviar formulario</button>
</form>
```

Aqui el jquery:

```js
$("#submit_agregar_producto").click(function (e) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        if($('#proveedor').val() == '' || $('#producto').val()=='' || $('#precio').val()=='' || $('#cantidad').val()=='')
        {   
            $('#alerta').html('<p class="mal">Complete todos los campos</p>').show();
            
            return false;
        }
        
        $.ajax({
            url:"registro-producto.php",
            type:"post",
            processData:false,
            contentType:false,
            cache:false,    
            data:new FormData($("#submit_agregar_producto")[0]),
            dataType:"text",
            
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#loader').show();
            },
            success:function(r){
                console.log(r);
                r=r.trim();

                if(r == 'errorDatos'){
                    $('#alerta').html('<p class="mal">Error al registrar el producto</p>').show();
                    
                }   
                if(r == 'save'){
                    $('#alerta').html('<p class="bien">Producto agregado correctamente</p>').show();
                    // limpia el formulario si se inserto correctamente
                    $('#form_agregar_producto').trigger("reset");
                }
                
                
            },
            error: function(r){
                   console.log("Error",r);
                },
            // se ejecuta sin importa si falla o no
            complete: function() {
                $('#loader').hide();
             }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes pasar la data del `form` no el `bottom`:

**cambiar:**

```
data:new FormData($("#submit_agregar_producto")[0]),
```

**por**

```
data:new FormData($("#form_agregar_producto")),
```

en el $.ajax